# Beamer super-wide pages overlap between monitors

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I am trying to use the package `pgfpages` with the option `\setbeameroption{previous slide on second screen=left}` to create super wide pages to take advangate of multiple monitors. This is what I get in my PDF reader.

[image]

Since the Start icon is not aligned with the vertical box, it means that a part of the preview on the left will be shown on the projector monitor (because everything to the left of the startup icon will be shown on the projector). Some people may say that it has nothing to do with LaTeX, but a good workaround can be done with LaTeX; if I can insert an empty space between the two slides (in the vertical box position), then the two slides will be separated and any overlap will appear as white space rather than as a part of the content of the other slide. It could also be nice if the background of the empty space can be customized so that it blends with the background of the left slide (in case it was not white).

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}
\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.3\paperwidth}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{previous slide on second screen=left}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually without Alert}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
        %
        \uncover<+->{\vphantom{$1$}}\uncover<+->{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

        \begin{description}[<+->]
            \item[Rigid] Rigid
            \item[Cheap] Cheap
                \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}}
            \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
                \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}}
            \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
        \end{description}

    \end{block}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another approach: instead of trying to change change the layout, use a pdf viewer that is capable to deal with multiple monitors. One great tool for mac is http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/, but similar tools exist for other operating systems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the re-defined `previous slide on second screen` layout you could define a custom one and move the pages around as you please (I marked the two places to adjust values with `<-...`):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeft}{1.5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRight}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRight}{2mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=\widthTextMarginLeft, text margin right=\widthTextMarginRight}
\newlength{\sidebarWidth}
\setlength{\sidebarWidth}{0.3\paperwidth}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\sidebarWidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{previous slide on second screen=left}


\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green}

\makeatletter
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{my two screens with lagging second}
{}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptiontwoheight,%
    physical width=2.5\paperwidth,% <- change "2.5" to adjust total paper width
    last logical shipout=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    center=\pgfpoint{2\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight},% <- change the "2" to horizontally move left page
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight},%
    copy from=1%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{my two screens with lagging second}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Showing Contents Gradually without Alert}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
        %
        \uncover<+->{\vphantom{$1$}}\uncover<+->{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

        \begin{description}[<+->]
            \item[Rigid] Rigid
            \item[Cheap] Cheap
                \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}}
            \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
                \note<+>{\blindlistlist[1]{enumerate}}
            \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
        \end{description}

    \end{block}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly is the parameter that adjusts the width of the clearance between slides? Also, how to adjust the color of that clearance?

Comment: I can move the frame around the canvas but not control the canvas aspect ratio width/height in fact that value at start seems redundant, am I missing something?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I marked the two parameters to adjust. One determines the total width and with the other one you can horizontally move the right slide. With these two parameters you can adjust the gap in the middle.

Comment: @KJO In the above example the height will be equal to the height of the frames. The aspect ratio can thus be changed by modifying the total width of the page with the lines I annotated with `adjust total paper width`